# Software deployment process

Tags: java, spring, maven, jenkins, deployment

I'm working on Java/Spring Web application and have a question about software build process, especially about stage and prod environments.

Right now, at the current project we have a following process - we are merging Git dev code branch to stage and then building and deploying the project using Maven and Jenkins to stage environment. Once stage is verified we are merging stage to master Git branch and again building and deploying the project using Maven and Jenkins to production.

Is it a correct process ? Do we need to build a separate war files for stage and prod environments(like we currently do) or do we need to build a single war file, deploy it to stage env and supply with stage parameters, test and verify it and then deploy the same war file to prod environment but with a prod parameters ?

In case of second approach how to correctly parameterize single application that must be running on Tomcat with different parameters for stage and prod ? Also, we are using Maven filtering feature.. how to deal with it also in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When promoting a version from staging to production, you typically want to deploy that exact same binary version to production, to make sure that the version you tested on staging will behave the same in production.

When you make a new build for production, you have no guarantee that it will behave the same as the build you made for staging. For all you know, the Java version or some other tool on your build server could have changed in between.

There are multiple ways to solve the configuration challenge. You should start with stripping all environment-specific configuration from your application (a WAR in your case), so you can use the same binary through all your environments. 
Next, you can either:

1. Manage the configuration on the target environments itself manually
   or
2. use a provisioning system like Puppet or Chef to roll out configuration changes automatically
   or (the option below has my preference:)
3. Build packages (just plain zip files) with configuration for each environment.
   Example build result:

   - application.war
   - config-tst.zip
   - config-stg.zip
   - config-prd.zip

So, when you deploy to your test environment, you deploy the war and unzip config-tst.zip. When you deploy to staging, you deploy the same war and config-stg.zip, etc.

Hope this helps, good luck!